# Calling a method from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

For a turn-based game I want to make a build queue for a planet. User puts items to build in a queue and then, when turn is generated, everything in a queue is being built.

Right now I have a Planet class which has an ArrayList. An object of type Planet is created for each planet the player owns. The array list contains everything user has ordered this planet to build. It also contains 3 variables that store the resources currently present on the planet and 3 variables that store total number of buildings that are currently on the planet.

Every building type is also a class (because building types costs differ), I plan to put objects of corresponding type into the planets queue. I suppose that each building class should have its own building method **.build()**;

I want to cycle through each item in the queue of the planet and launch something like **.buld()** method.
Building an object means subtracting some resources from the planets resource variables and adding number of buildings built to total number of buildings on a planet.
The trouble is that I don't understand the main idea, how to achieve this.

The Planet class:

```
public class Planet extends WorldObject implements Serializable {

    private int defenses;
    private int mines;
    private int factories;
    //it also has 3 variables from WorldObject class:
    int iron;
    int bor;
    int ger;

    ArrayList<Installation> queue;

    private void build(){
        for ( int i = 0; i < queue.size()-1; i++ )
        {
            queue.get(i).build();
        }
    }
}
```

One of the building classes:

```
 public class Factory extends Installation {
        int costIron = 10;
        int costGer = 50;

        public build(int amt) {                
            //build itself, remove res from planet, add number built to planet factory list
        }    
    }
```

If I'm doing this totally wrong, I would be thankful if you say in which "direction" should I look for information.

Comment: Your `build` method in `Factory` has a parameter - whereas you're calling a `build()` method with no arguments in `Installation`. If you're confused about why your build method isn't being called, that's why...

Comment: Is it on purpose that the `for` loop "ignores" the last element in the `queue` list? If not, then change the termination condition to `i < queue.size()` (remove the `-1`).

Comment: Why are you doing this totally wrong? Because you want it to be better designed or just something doesn't work?

Comment: You've done a good job describing your scenario, but I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Between your text and your code, sure, you have a lot left to do, but which bit are you here for help with, exactly?

Comment: >>>Is it on purpose that the for loop "ignores" the last element in the queue list?
It is a mistake :)

>>>Why are you doing this totally wrong? Because you want it to be better designed or just something doesn't work?
I want to find a good "Java way" to do this. Because I'm still learning, I want to find out what is the "good style" to program this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `Planet` should have a `Resources` object that encapsulates the resources, and that could be passed to `Installation.build()`. Then `Installation.build()`  could return a object that describes what was built.

*Edit: here's an example:*

```
public class MineFactory extends Installation {
    private final Resources cost;

    public MineFactory(Resources cost) {
      this.cost = cost.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public Result build(Resources availableResources) {    
      if (!availableResources.remove(cost)) {
        return Result.empty();
      }
      return Result.mines(2);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: This one is nice, but author doesn't look interested in anymore :)

Comment: Looks like a way out :) I will try this.

Comment: @Zmur I hope it worked out. If you did, please accept the answer :-)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Have some non-programming trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass your `Planet`  object to `build` as an argument so that it has access to resources, or, alternatively, do the "building" in the `Panet` code itself, and just have `getCost` on the building, that you'd call yo find out how much resources to subtract.

Personally, I'd know kinda prefer the latter approach, but that's more of a question if taste than anything else.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that method, because Planet has some other things to do and I don't want that class to be to long.
But I'll try to the first method you advised, perhaps it will work for me :)